# MKPinAnnotationView doesn't show in MKMapView even though it's properly added using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview

I'm developing an OSX app.

I've subclassed a MKAnnotation:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class LocationAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var image: NSImage?
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(image anImage: NSImage?, title aTitle: String, coordinate aCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.image = anImage
        self.title = aTitle
        self.coordinate = aCoordinate
    }
}
```

In my NSViewController subclass, I've added a MKMapViewDelegate and in Interface Builder I've added a MKMapView and set its delegate to NSViewController.

To find out what's wrong, I'm adding three locations in my *ViewDidLoad* method, into an array. I'm adding those annotations to my map in *ViewDidAppear*. I plan to move that to a background thread when I figure out what's wrong.

```
import Cocoa
import MapKit

class ShowLocationsViewController: NSViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var locationMap: MKMapView!

    private var myLocationArray: [LocationAnnotation] = []
    private var myRegion: MKCoordinateRegion!

    //#MARK: - UIViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myLocationArray = []
        myRegion = nil

        let locLondon = LocationAnnotation(image: nil, title: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.522617, -0.139371))
        let locWembley = LocationAnnotation(image: nil, title: "Wembley", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.555909, -0.279600))
        let locGreenwich = LocationAnnotation(image: nil, title: "Greenwich", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.476572, -0.001596))

        myLocationArray.append(locLondon)
        myLocationArray.append(locWembley)
        myLocationArray.append(locGreenwich)

        myRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: locLondon.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.20, 0.20)) // 20km span
    }

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        locationMap.addAnnotations(myLocationArray)
        locationMap.setRegion(myRegion, animated: true)
    }
}
```

When using delegate's method *viewFor annotation:* I print out the title of each annotation in a log and all three of them are listed. In another delegate's method *didAdd* I'm printing out the number of annotations of my map in a log and it prints out three. But on my map, there are no annotations displayed. I tried panning and zooming with no success. Region gets properly set and displayed though.

```
//#MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    print(locationMap.annotations.count, views.count)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is LocationAnnotation {
        let annotationIdentifier = "Location"

        var annotationView = locationMap.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) as! MKPinAnnotationView?
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        }

        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true

        print(annotationView!.annotation!.title ?? "no view")

        return annotationView
    } else {
        print("no annotation")
        return nil
    }
}
```

When I try the same code in an iOS app, everything works. I assume there is nothing wrong with my delegate because methods are properly called.

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: If I make a new project, and copy the code posted above, everything works ok. So definitely is something wrong with my project, but don't know where to start. I tried to clean and rebuild the project but nothing has changed to the better.

My ViewController is set up in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, the way the window is being called.

I created a variable *mainWindowController* in my AppDelegate, then I subclassed my main NSViewController so that I could hook up AppDelegate to it.

```
let appDelegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.mainWindowController = self
```

Afterwards I used this code to call my window which was errornous:

```
let mapViewController = mainWindowController?.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier.init(rawValue: "ShowLocationsID")) as! ShowLocationsViewController
mainWindowController?.contentViewController?.presentViewControllerAsModalWindow(mapViewController)
```

I changed that in a way that I created a segue in my storyboard and called the following code which worked and my pins did show:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(rawValue: "ShowLocations"), sender: self)
```